# Dynamically change page action property in NAV

Tags: dynamics-nav

I am a newbie in NAV. I have a requiremen to change the page action property PromotedOnly to YES dynamically. Is it possible and if so how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot alter the Property "PromotedOnly" at runtime.
A possible Workaround (not a nice one!) could be to create two Actions - on wirh "PromotedOnly" = yes and on with "PromotedOnly" = no. Then you can use a global boolean variable so alter the "Visible"-Property of these Actions at runtime to show only one of them.